# How to use dict value and key in Snakemake rules

Tags: python, snakemake

I stuck in a Snakemake issue for a lone while.

Propose I have a dict like:

```
dict_A = {A:"id1","id2","id3", B:"id2","id3","id4","id5", C:"id1","id4","id5"}
```

and I want to write rules like:

```
input:
    "{dict_A.keys()}/{dict_A[key]}_R1.txt"
output:
    "{dict_A.keys()}/{dict_A[key]}_R1_filter.txt"
shell:
    "XXX {input} > {output}"
```

While, I try to search on google and StackOverflow but I can't figure out this problem. Really hope there is someone can help me !

Really thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example of what input and output filenames look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snakemake works by providing it a final output we expect it to generate, and rules how to produce output from certain input. When we do not define any output on the command line, snakemake will try to generate the input of the first rule in your Snakefile. So we define a `rule all` with as input what we want to generate:

```
dict_A = {'A': ["id1","id2","id3"], 
          'B': ["id2","id3","id4","id5"], 
          'C': ["id1","id4","id5"]}

all_input = []
for key, values in dict_A.items():
    for value in values:
        all_input.append(f"{key}/{value}_R1_filter.txt")

rule all:
    input:
        all_input
```

Now we have to change our rule so that it can fill in the correct wildcards for the output it wants to generate:

```
rule do_sth_cool:
    input:
        "{key_wc}/{value_wc}_R1.txt"
    output:
        "{key_wc}/{value_wc}_R1_filter.txt"
    shell:
        "XXX {input} > {output}"
```

Take a look again at the [docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and make yourself familiar with the basic concepts of snakemake.

edit:

```
rule all:
    input:
        [f"{key}/{value}_R1_filter.txt" for key, values in dict_A.items() for value in values]
```

Comment: LOL, Thank you, and I just use this method to run the analysis pipeline. But I just confused if there could be a concise method~

Comment: What do you mean with more concise?

Comment: If there could be a method, which we can use a dict key and dict value in `input` part at the same time, rather than make a file list by ourselves.

Comment: It is not possible to directly use a dictionary, since how would Python/Snakemake know which key/value to use? And that it has to unpack the list of values? I made an edit with a *"consise"* solution where we unpack the dictionary ourselves. If this works for you don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Okay, I see... Thanks again!